# cascading filter in performance point server , sharepoint 2010

Tags: filter, performancepoint

i need to create the cascading filter in performancepoint server. i dont know how can i do this.

Answer (score 2):

Hei Bart. Check out http://blogs.msdn.com/b/performancepoint/archive/2011/08/03/cascading-filters-in-performancepoint-services.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what you need to do from such a brief description, but take a look at SPCascadeDropdowns in my SPServices jQuery library: http://spservices.codeplex.com.

Answer (score 0):

Cascading PPS Filters will be available in performancepoint services when service pack 1 is released.